# How to convert preg_replace e to preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Okay, so I'm slightly confused. Here is the code I have now, but I just found out the `e` modifier is deprecated. How do I convert it to a `preg_replace_callback()`? I still haven't figured it out.

```
$post = preg_replace("/\[code\]([^] )\[\/code\]/e", 'code(\'$1\')', $post);
```

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If memory serves, `preg_replace_callback()` gives you the results of a `$match` from `preg_match()` as input, and expects the final result as output. So you'd need to write a function that returns e.g. `"code('{$match[1]}')"`.

It can be an inline function, naturally, if php 5.3 is an option:

```
preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
  // do stuff
  return $stuff;
}, $subject);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot. I will accept when it lets me.