# Replace deprecated preg_replace with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

code below gives a deprecation warning after upgrading to PHP 5.5+

```
$sentence=preg_replace('/~([^<>]{1,})~/e', "'<span class=\"helpstart\">'.UTF8_strtoupper('\\1').'</span>'", $sentence);
```

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in ..

How can I replace the code with preg_replace_callback()?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear, you just return the value you would want the match to be replaced with in a callback function : http://in3.php.net/preg_replace_callback

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert preg\_replace e to preg\_replace\_callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367404/how-to-convert-preg-replace-e-to-preg-replace-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sentence=preg_replace('/~([^<>]{1,})~/', function($match) {return "<span class=\"helpstart\">".UTF8_strtoupper($match)."</span>"; } , $sentence);
```

as per http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: if i change preg_replace with preg_replace_callback and fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$sentence=preg_replace_callback('/~([^<>]{1,})~/', function($match) {return "<span class=\"helpstart\">".UTF8_strtoupper($match[1])."</span>"; } , $sentence);
```

The first answer was an error on the function.