# Change preg_replace into preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to replace the following string:

> \u0080\u009cone hand rule\u0080\u009d

As I have to replace those codes for many strings and as there are various combinations of \u0080\u009 like \u00e2\u0080\u0099 and \u00a0 I ve searched for an solution to convert them all back into their according value.

The solution i ve found was posted on this site: http://www.avoid.org/replace-u-characters-in-json-string/

```
preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", 
             "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8', pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))",  
              json_encode($struct));
```

As i was trying to use this code php threw the following error:

> Deprecated:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead

Since I'm relativley new to php i bareley understand the preg_replace in first place but with the conversion to preg_replace_callback i'm totally overstrained. I've looked up [How to convert preg_replace e to preg_replace_callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367404/how-to-convert-preg-replace-e-to-preg-replace-callback) but i didnt get it :/

Could somone pls explain how to convert my preg_replace into preg_replace_callback?

The code I m trying to get to work looks now like this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})",
              function($match){
                return = iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')), $match[1]);                    
              }, 
              json_encode($string));
```

I ve read and understood how to access my found matches but since the

> "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8', pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))",

from the original code doesnt access any of the matches found I'm quiet confused how to set up my anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.5.0 E_DEPRECATED level error is emitted when passing in the "\e" modifier. As of PHP 7.0.0 E_WARNING is emited in this case and "\e" modifier has no effect.

Please visit [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for documentation

"/\\u([a-f0-9]{4})"  = > "/\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/"